# Floating columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/Chris-Brennan/pen/pjjELq

Also here's a pic of what im trying to do http://s1.postimg.org/elbjj3ifz/temp.jpg

Stack col-1 & col-3 on top of each other floated to the left. height 300px
Stack col-2 & col-4 on top of each floated to the right height 300px
The middle column I named the header(the pic of al green) height 600px

I need col-3 to snap in place underneath col-1. 
I need col-4 to snap in place underneath col-2
I tried clearing the floats and nothing worked. I tried using the classes pull-left and pull-right with no success.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" id="colxs12">col-1</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" id="header"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" id="colxs12">col-2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12"  id="colxs13">col-3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12"  id="colxs14">col-4</div>
</div>
</div>


.container {
text-align: center;
}
#colxs12{
height:300px;
background:skyblue;
border:1px solid black;
}
#colxs13{
float:left;
height:300px;
background:skyblue;
border:1px solid black;

}
#colxs14{
float:right;
height:300px;
background:skyblue;
border:1px solid black;
}
#header{
background:url(http://www.edgallucciphotography.com/site/wp- content/gallery/al-green/6-al-green_b1-f12y.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height:600px;
 }
 #header h1{
 color:white;
 }
 #table{
 margin-top:20px;
 width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a pic of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Added. srry I forgot :/ Also had an error in what I was trying to do. Re-read the problem above. Thx

Comment: Chris, a pic of what you wanna achieve would be great. `:)`

Comment: http://s1.postimg.org/elbjj3ifz/temp.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Divide your layout into three columns and have the first and last column have two rows with column each. Second column will just have one row with the picture. Don't bother with floats and remember to specify width: 100% so the columns use the whole space provided

Basically, something like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" id="colxs12">col-1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" id="colxs13">col-3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" id="header"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" id="colxs12">col-2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" id="colxs14">col-4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
    text-align: center;
  }
#colxs12{
  height:300px;
  width: 100%;
  background:skyblue;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#colxs13{
  width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  background:skyblue;
  border:1px solid black;

}
#colxs14{
  width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  background:skyblue;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#header{
  background:url(http://www.edgallucciphotography.com/site/wp-content/gallery/al-green/6-al-green_b1-f12y.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:600px;
  width: 100%;
}
#header h1{
  color:white;
}
#table{
  margin-top:20px;
  width:500px;
}
```

Comment: ya, know I could probably take away the 100% width's and set the rows to a class "fluid"